# Can we safely assign an object reference from a socket argument's callback

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if i am doing something dangerous by assigning the reference of an Object i receive from a callback to another variable, it is possible to "loose" this data?

A very simple exemple which happens on the server side, from a socket's callback:

```
var Users [];
socket.on('receive-user', function(User) {
  Users.push(User);
});
```

Here, i push a reference of the variable `User` into my array `Users`, but i couldn't explain what becomes the original variable `User` at the end of the scope, so, is it dangerous ? Are there possibilities for this reference to change at the next callback ?

I also do this when i get a Model from a database fetch, or even to store the socket itself into a `User` variable, but i am really wondering if it's not a big mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. As long as there's something still referencing the `User` object (in this case your Users array) then it won't be garbage collected.

This is normally how a garbage collected language works. Which is one reason you don't see `malloc` et al. in garbage collected languages -- basically all variable declarations are `malloc'ed`.